# Validate project name programmatically

Tags: c#, cls

I am working on a tool that uses the [Microsoft.Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145008%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespaces, to programmatically build a C# project, among other things. The projects can be created via Visual Studio or generated using parameter substitution of code template.

I need to validate that the given project is a valid one. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975257/regular-expression-to-match-valid-namespace-name) that has rules for a valid project name, but I believe the list is incomplete.

For example - as per the C# CLS - an identifier cannot be used in a project name, unless it is prefixed with `@`. Referred [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x53a06bb(v=vs.110).aspx). Another example is, if the input project name is a number, then Visual Studio prefixes it with an underscore.

So, question is - is there a namespace/api/fancy regular expression that I can use to create a new C# project programmatically, outside of Visual Studio, that will apply all such rules that the C# CLS specifies?

Comment: Your question should be in the format: "I am looking for a regex that matches these rules [list rules], this is what I have so far [show current efforts]". As it stands, you are basically asking us to go and search for the rules for you

Comment: @musefan - I believe I listed some rules that are not consistent(at least to me). I even refered to the MSDN doc that I have been referring for a rule. I am not looking for the rules - I am rather looking at a (possible) API similar to `Microsoft.Build` that could do this for me. Am happy to take an answer that says it does not exist!

Comment: Asking for an API is also considered "off-topic". I suggest you just go with the rules you know/find and leave it at that. What's the worst that can happen if you miss a rule?